# How to find a input hidden element in jquery ajax success html response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling function via ajax and I am getting the data properly, but I am not able to access the hidden elements in html returned.

#### Code:

```
success: function(data){
        var $response = $(data);
        var errorMessage = $response.filter('#errorMessage').val();
        alert(errorMessage);
            
}
```

I am getting `"undefined"` alert. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `find` method:

```
var errorMessage = $response.find('#errorMessage').val();
```