# Ajax & Grails - how to use the params from the model in the success of the Ajax?

Tags: ajax, grails, controller

I have an Ajax which call to an action in a controler.

The controller render:

```
render template:"changePassword", model:[user: user, passwordError: passwordError]
```

The `passwordError` is  boolean.

In case the `passwordError` is true I have to perform  function in the js.file.

How can I check in the success's Ajax the value of the  `passwordError`?

The code of the Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: changePassword,
    type: "post",
    data: {
        password: $('#password').val(), npassword: $('#npassword').val()
    },
    success: function(data,textStatus){
        $('#changePassSuceess').modal()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont need to render a template, you can return a json as @Eylen mentioned and then access the flag from json. If you must render a template then you can have a hidden field in your template with value set to the flag passwordError and then you can get the value of flag from this hidden field in your javascript code

See this question for [how to find hidden element in jquery ajax response html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130624/how-to-find-a-input-hidden-element-in-jquery-ajax-success-html-response)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to show the template that you are returning, then you can change your return from the controller to something like the following

```
return [passwordChanged:true] as JSON
```

Ans then in your ajax call you will have access to the JSON object in the data attribute.

```
console.log(data.passwordChanged);
```

Maybe you have to tell also in the ajax call that the return type is json.